# AspNetCore AspIdentity Dependency Injection of PasswordHaserOptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

How to provide an override of the default PasswordHasherOptions, so that the AspNetCore V3 [PasswordHasher](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/bfec2c14be1e65f7dd361a43950d4c848ad0cd35/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PasswordHasherOptions.cs) uses [PasswordHasherOptions](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/bfec2c14be1e65f7dd361a43950d4c848ad0cd35/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PasswordHasherOptions.cs) **V2**?

The [V3 PasswordHasher extension default constructor](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/2b2aeee9f869ec43f65c188a66d9285858823628/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PasswordHasher.cs#L42)
needs `IOptions<PasswordHasherOptions>`, what is the AddSingleton??? syntax to provide custom PasswordHasherOptions? Where the PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode is set to 'IdentityV2'

Related to an [Aspidentity 2.2 (framework 4.x) reused on AspnetCore AspIdentity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56246853/aspidentity-2-2-framework-4-x-reused-on-aspnetcore-aspidentity)

Answer (score 1):

Use `services.Configure` (in `Startup.ConfigureServices`) to register `IOptions` configuration objects. In this case, it's most easily done with the [overload that takes a delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configure-simple-options-with-a-delegate):

```
services.Configure<PasswordHasherOptions>(o => o.CompatibilityMode = PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV2);
```

Comment: Thankyou, yes, as per: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration